# Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\SalesmanController::show does not exist

Tags: php, function, laravel-8, pg-column-does-not-exist-error

I'm using laravel 8 on api call it is giving such type of error

```
public function  getSalesman(){

       $salesman = Salesman::where('deleted_at', '=', null)->get(['id', 'name']);

       return response()->json([
           'salesman' => $salesman,
       ]);

   }
```

Comment: Can you share the routes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

may be you have not show method in this controller!